# Is there a blank Unicode character matching emoji width?

Tags: unicode, emoji

Does Unicode define a blank character (like "Em Space" or "En Space") with the same width as any/some emoji (something like "Emoji Space")? If yes, which one is it?

I'd like to be able to format a fixed-width font plain-text table containing emojis (CI report e-mail). They seem to be impossible to align either with regular or any other spaces I tried (compare "x86_64", "arm" and "mips" lines):

```
                                                                                               
    Status                                                                                     
        ❌ 13 / 733 builds FAILED                                                              
    Architectures                                                                              
        x86_64       ✅ 82  ❓ 4                                                               
        aarch64      ✅ 6                                                                      
        ppc64le      ✅ 5                                                                      
        s390x        ✅ 5                                                                      
        mips    ❌ 9 ✅ 77                                                                     
        arm64        ✅ 73                                                                     
        arm     ❌ 4 ✅ 282 ❓ 4                                                               
        i386         ✅ 30                                                                     
        sparc        ✅ 9                                                                      
        riscv        ✅ 33                                                                     
        arc          ✅ 10                                                                     
        s390         ✅ 21                                                                     
        powerpc      ✅ 52                                                                     
        sh           ✅ 18                                                                     
        parisc       ✅ 9
```

Applying VS16 to space/letters, or VS15 to emojis, largely didn't work (in Firefox, Chrome and Thunderbird):

```
|   |
|❌︎✅︎❓︎|
| ️ ️ ️|
|❌✅❓|
```

Comment: Here's a handy list of code points in category "Zs": https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Zs But I'm not sure how or if the width of Emojis is defined relative to any of those.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer at this moment seems to be "no". A workaround could be using another emoji, closest in meaning to "nothing", depending on your context. E.g. this is what I'm going with in our CI emails:

```
BUILDS

    Status
                 ❌ 4  ✅ 712
    Architectures
         x86_64  ➖    ✅  82
        aarch64  ➖    ✅   6
        ppc64le  ➖    ✅   5
          s390x  ➖    ✅   5
           mips  ➖    ✅  77
          arm64  ➖    ✅  73
            arm  ❌ 4  ✅ 282
           i386  ➖    ✅  30
          sparc  ➖    ✅   9
          riscv  ➖    ✅  33
            arc  ➖    ✅  10
           s390  ➖    ✅  21
        powerpc  ➖    ✅  52
             sh  ➖    ✅  18
         parisc  ➖    ✅   9
```

Comment: does `tab` or `tab + U+FE0F` work in your case?

Comment: @phuclv, unfortunately not. Thunderbird still shows the columns unaligned.

Comment: Another ball dropped by Unicode. And I am only saying that because I love Unicode. We need more hard-core devs on the Unicode team because at version 15, not being able to align unicode emoji in a grid because there exists not a single blank character in the entirety of the Unicode code space that has the same width is a pretty big oversight! Sadly for us, the problem is that a space character already exists (multiple!) so it seems hard to add one without breaking stuff or introducing yet more 'whitespace' characters...

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a font issue. You'd need a monospace font with a glyph for U+2705 WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK and the other characters, and make sure to disable Emojis with a variation selector. Web browsers typically replace missing characters with a fallback font, but then you lose control over character spacing. Your best bet is to use characters which are more likely to be supported. Unfortunately, even U+2713 CHECK MARK seems to be supported [only in a few monospace fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=%E2%9D%8C%20%E2%9C%85%20%E2%9C%93%20%E2%9C%97&preview.text_type=custom&category=Monospace).

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry, I'm not sure how that helps me. My browser/terminal/e-mail client all support both of these characters, and variant selectors don't help, as I mention in my question. Another answer suggesting those was deleted here. Could you clarify?

Comment: Do you mean VS15 didn't work for me because the particular font doesn't have the character corresponding to "textified" emoji, and that fonts having those are hard to come by? If so, that explains the problem, thank you. Unfortunately I cannot dictate which fonts recipients use, as I'm sending plain-text emails. Some recipients might not even have emojis in their fonts at all.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to use a monospaced font that has the lineHeight (EM) equal to that of the emoji font at the same font size.

For Apple's system emoji font, the obvious choice would be the system monospaced font SF Mono.

So, here you go:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot control which font the recipient uses, I can only expect them to use *a* monospace font.

Comment: maybe try tabs instead of spaces?

Comment: Thank you, already suggested in the comments above, and doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Looking at this again just now, your screenshot has the green check boxes slightly out of alignment on `mips` and `arm` lines, and the red question marks unaligned as well.

Comment: @spbnick Didn't realize Apple has different kerning settings between SF fonts and Apple Color Emoji. A 10% looser kerning / character spacing would solve the issue.